# Android studio sqlite to listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

On create method;

```
     db = openOrCreateDatabase("messages", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message(msg TEXT);");
     db.execSQL("INSERT INTO message values('example');");
     listeview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
     ArrayList<String> dbArray = myArrayListTodatabase();
     ListAdapter mylistadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dbArray);
        listview.setAdapter(mylistadapter);
```

Myarraylisttodatabase code;

```
public ArrayList<String> myArrayListTodatabase() {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("messages", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.rawQuery("Select * from message", null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from message", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String dbString = "";
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("msg")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("msg"));
            dbString += "\n";

        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return myArraylist;
}
```

Global variables

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
public ArrayList<String> myArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Im using these but there is no output in listview when i run the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to insert into ArrayList. Update your function with below one:

```
public ArrayList<String> myArrayListTodatabase() {
    myArraylist.clear();
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("messages", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.rawQuery("Select * from message", null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from message", null);
    String dbString = "";
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        if (!c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("msg")).equals("")) {
            myArraylist.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("msg")));
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return myArraylist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding content to the ArrayList at all. Add `myArraylist.Add(dbString)` or something to fill your ArrayList for your ListView to use.